# A question on homogeneous Besov space of negative order

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f \in (L^2 (\mathbb R^n))^n$, i.e. $f$ is a vector-valued function. We assume $\nabla \cdot f = 0$ and $\int (1+\mid x \mid)\mid f(x) \mid dx < \infty$.

How can I show that $$f \in (\dot B_2^{-\frac{n+2}{2},\infty})^n \iff \sup_{j \in \mathbb Z}\int_{\frac{1}{2} \leq 2^j \mid \xi \mid \leq 1} \mid \mathcal F(f) \mid^2 \frac{d\xi}{\mid \xi \mid^{n+2}} < \infty.$$

where $\mathcal F$ denotes the Fourier transform.

I just started learning Besov spaces, and looked up relevant notes, but still  can't show the equivalence above.

Updated.

Comment: Your question seems somewhat incomplete. The variable $j $ from the $\sup $ appears nowhere else and there seems to be an integral sign missing.

Comment: @PhoemueX You are right. Just updated.